# jquery autocomplete showing no search results although in response

Tags: jquery, jsp, autocomplete

I am trying to implement jquery autocomplete in a java/jsp project.

The autocomplete function executes properly even takes the term to the server. The server sends the necessary response too that is visible in developer tools. The problem is that autocomplete is showing `No search results` even after getting the response.

Here is my ajax jsp page - **ajaxOtherLocations.jsp** -  where I am querying for results.

```
<%
  String query = (String)request.getParameter("term");
  System.out.println(query);
  LocationDAO locationModel = new LocationDAO();
  ArrayList<LocationBean> locations = locationModel.getLocationsByType("others");

  for( LocationBean location : locations )
  {
   out.print(location.getLocationName()+"\n");
  }
%>
```

In developer tools in network tab I can see that a request is being sent to the above page and response is something like...

```
LBNagar
Hitech City
Jubilee Hills
Film Nagar
Lakdikapool
Koti
Dilsukhnagar
```

All separated by `line-end` character as you can see.

I am calling the `autocomplete` function like this...

```
$(".auto-complete").keypress(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({source:"ajax/ajaxOtherLocations.jsp"});
    });
```

Where am I doing wrong?

NOTE: - I took ideas from this tutorial - http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/example-get-autocomplete-feature-in-javajsp-with-jquery-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using jquery auto complete and in that case you need to return data in json format. You can refer below link:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: I know JSON will work. My question is the above mention method is working for someone without JSON so where am I going wrong with this one?